# Download all files from SFTP folder to local folder using PHP

Tags: php, sftp

I try to move all files from SFTP folder to a local folder.

I use the following script:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('x.x.x.x', 22);

if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'User_login', 'User_Pass')) {
    throw new Exception('Impossible de ce connencter.');
}

if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) {
    throw new Exception('Impossible de ce connencter.');
}

$files = array();
$dirHandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/01_Folder/");

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirHandle))) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Thanks Guys.

Comment: you can't use SFTP to put files on an FTP server they are two different things.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, The FTP Server is the Local stream, he launch script to remote the SFTP server to get a file.

Comment: So how does *"another remote ftp server"* in your question go with *"The FTP Server is the Local stream"* in your comment?

Comment: Thanks guys i found solution ==>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run rsync from Php using the [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. It will ask you for user name and password of the remote server. You can bypass that using the [SSHPass](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) command line tool. It allows non interactive login. The following command runs rsync with sshpass:

```
rsync --rsh="sshpass -p myPassword ssh -l username" server.example.com:/var/www/html/ /backup/
```

The command can be run from Php using the exec function

Comment: thanks Mr Nadir, it's a real solution i prefere this method (y)

Comment: But it has nothing to do with SFTP, what was your question about.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download all files from the SFTP directory to local directory - *local* as of the PHP script (if that's what you call *"FTP server"*):

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('sftp.example.com');

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$dirhandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/remote/folder/");

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirhandle)))
{
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
    {
        $remotehandle = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/remote/folder/$file", 'r');
        $localhandle = fopen("/local/folder/$file", 'w');
        stream_copy_to_stream($remotehandle, $localhandle);
        fclose($remotehandle);
        fclose($localhandle);
    }
}
```

*Add error checking!*

Answer (score 1):

solution for interested persons ==>

```
//connecxion
$connection = ssh2_connect('remote.server.com', 22);
// Authentication
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'Login_user', 'Password')) {
    throw new Exception('Impossible de ce connencter.');
}

// Creation de la source SFTP 
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)) {
    throw new Exception('Impossible de ce connencter.');
}


$files = array();
$dirHandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/Remote_folder/");

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirHandle))) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}


if (count($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $fileName) {
        // Dossier Change
        if (!$remoteStream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/Remote_folder/$fileName", 'r')) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to open remote file: $fileName");
        } 

        // Dossier Local
        if (!$localStream = @fopen("/local_folder/$fileName", 'w')) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to open local file for writing: /var/www/change_files/$fileName");
        }

        // Ecriture du dossier change dans le dossier Local
        $read = 0;
        $fileSize = filesize("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/Remote_folder/$fileName");
        while ($read < $fileSize && ($buffer = fread($remoteStream, $fileSize - $read))) {
            $read += strlen($buffer);

            // Ecriture du dossier
            if (fwrite($localStream, $buffer) === FALSE) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to write to local file: /local_folder/$fileName");
            }
        }

        // Fermeture des Connexions
        fclose($localStream);
        fclose($remoteStream);
    }
}
```